# Windows Server 2008 RC - Connection Erros - Apache Benchmark

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

If we want tu run some benchmark, the following

```
/ab.exe -n 500 -c 300 -v 1000 -k http://server:port/test.html
```

lead to an "connection refused":

```
Test aborted after 10 failures

apr_socket_connect(): Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.   (730061)
```

It is possible to deactive the "limit"? Which limit is applied? We see nothing in the Windows event log.

If we call less connections it works:

```
./ab.exe -n 500 -c 257 -k http://server:port/test.html
```

Does anyone knows ho to find the corresponding limit? And mabe how to deactivate, because we have not enough hosts to use different IPs for the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to uncomment the MPM config include in httpd.conf

```
# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

Then locate the `mpm_winnt_module` and change the thread count from the current value to whatever you want.

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>
```